# Pickle sizes of various forms of Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm attempting to Pickle a large dataframe containing lots of datetimes. The dataframe was loaded from a CSV where the datetimes were stored as strings.

After loading the CSV into a Pandas Dataframe, converting the string datetimes to Pandas datetimes, and saving the dataframe to a Pickle file, I was surprised to see size of the pickle file was comparable to the original CSV.

Doing some investigation, it seems to me that Pickling a string representation of a datetime is smaller than a `datetime.datetime` type which in turn is significantly smaller than a Pandas Timestamp type.

```
import pandas
import pickle
import datetime
print(len(pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now(), 4)))
print(len(pickle.dumps(pandas.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.now()), 4)))
print(len(pickle.dumps("2021.12.25D12:34:56.789012345", 4)))
```

Output:

```
53
85
44
```

Why is the pickled size of the Pandas Timestamp so much larger than the `datetime.datetime` type and why are they both larger than the string representation?

Comment: Those types store a lot more info that than string does; timezone, resolution, etc.

Comment: @richardec, Thanks, that makes sense for the difference between string and datetime.datetime but what about the large difference between the Pandas Timestamp and the datetime?